# GTK call callback function of a widget

Tags: python, callback, event-handling, gtk

I have connected a callback function to the `realize` event of a widget.

The widget is a treeview and when it is realized it will fill the table from the database.
When I open up an entry from the table, it opens a window where I can edit the data.
Then I save the data, the window closes and the table might be refreshed.

So I call `treeview.emit('realize')` to call the function that fills the treeview again.
But the treeview is corrupted, no column headers and the callback function is not called.

I tried also:

```
treeview.unrealize()
treeview.realize()
```

some code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
b = Gtk.Builder()
b.add_from_file('file.glade')

def fill_table(treeview, table_name):
    'fills the treeview from database (select * from table_name ...)'
    ...

def open_entry(treeview, row ...):
    'opens the window of the entry'
    w = b.get_object('entry_window')
    ...

def save_and_fill(button):
    'when the SAVE button in the entry_window is clicked, it saves the data, closes the entry_window and fills the treeview'
    #update table1 set column=....
    b.get_object('treeview').emit('realize') #here it might call the fill_table funcion
    b.get_object('entry_window').hide()

signals = {'realize' : lambda *args: fill_table('table1'),
           'row-activated' : open_entry,
           'clicked' : save_and_fill}

b.connect_signals(signals)
b.get_object('main_window').show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

or just `treeview.realize()` but it doesn't work.

Is it posible to call the callback function witch is connected to the `realize` event of widget without destroying the widget?

Comment: Can you add more code, this is not sufficient to diagnose your issue.

Comment: First, you seem to have hijacked the realize-signal for your own purpose... If you want to call fill_table() from the button press handler, then call fill_table() from there: don't emit a totally unrelated signal of another object. Second, the way a treeview works is that it should automatically update whenever the data in the model (like ListStore) changes: there should be no reason to call any functions that touch the treeview from the button press handler: you should just modify data in the model.

Comment: I edited the code above. What if the function, which is connected to the `realize` event, is dynamically created at connection time? I want to get the function and call it or emit the `realize` event to call the function.

Comment: You really have no business emitting the realize signal. You can call fill_table() in the realize handler if you want (but like ebassi says, and idle handler would be better), and you can call fill_table() from the clicked handler.

Answer (score 1):

you should not emit the `GtkWidget::realize` yourself directly. you can only emit signals with `g_signal_emit()` (or equiavlent in the language binding) in two cases:

- it's inside the class installing the signal
- the signal is marked with the `G_SIGNAL_ACTION` flag

see: https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#GSignalFlags

also, you're misusing the `GtkWidget::realize` in the first place. the realize signal should only be used to allocate windowing system resources, like `GdkWindow` instances, not to build your widget. if you want to fill the model used by a `GtkTreeView`, either do that in a specific callback, or use a idle/timeout source inside the main loop.